# Apache Log format timestamp unable to get timezone offset

Tags: httpd.conf, apache2.4, apache2.2

```
LogFormat "{ \
        \"@timestamp\": \"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z}t\", \
        \"@version\": \"1\", \
        \"clientip\": \"%a\", \
        \"status\": %>s, \
        \"bytes\": %B, \
        \"request\": \"%U%q\", \
        \"referer\": \"%{Referer}i\", \
        \"useragent\": \"%{User-agent}i\" \
        }" combinedJSON
```

Outputs name of timestamp instead of +0400 for example:

```
"@timestamp": "2016-08-29T16:50:37 Pacific Daylight Time",
```

Should be:

```
"@timestamp": "2016-08-29T16:50:37 -0700",
```

Is there no way to extract the timezone offset instead of the timezone name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux'es strftime() the offset is lowercase 'z'. You used big 'Z' which is the timezone name / abbreviation.

(mod_log_config just passes the format to the systems strftime so it cannot really document the values)

Comment: I tried using both lowercase and upper case. Also this on a windows machine.

Comment: The manual for strftime on Wndows says it cannot provide the timezone offset.  mod_log_config can show it when you provide no pattern at all, but it's not an exact match for your pattern.  I am afraid there is no solution here without enhancing mod_log_config to provide just the TZ offset.

Comment: This worked for me `LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}t` (Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 8.4)