# apache httpd LogFormat not honoring strftime format

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, strftime

i need a 8601 timestamp in my httpd logs, but httpd appears to not be honoring its time formatting contract.  i'm using apache httpd 2.4.6.

i have a logging conf as follows:

```
ErrorLogFormat "{\
\"level\": \"%l\",\
...
\"timestamp\":\"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\"\
}"
ErrorLog /dev/stderr

LogLevel info
LogFormat "{\
\"logger\": \"common\",\
...
\"timestamp\":\"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\",\
}" combined

CustomLog /dev/stdout combined
```

as you can see, this is a compact json layout (yes, perhaps not perfectly escaped).

observe the timestamp fields.  when i log, a log message looks like this:

```
{"level": "notice", ... ,"timestamp":"Wed Dec 27 19:16:05 2017"}
```

httpd doesn't honor or properly format my timestamp as specified.  the docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats suggest this should work.

Even I simplify it to just a single format, like `%{%T}t`, i get the full datestring per above.

`%{%T}t` ==> `"Wed Dec 27 19:24:50 2017"`

interestingly,

`%{%usec_frac}t` ==>`"2017-12-27 19:24:22.443786"`

so their custom tokens seem to work.  all i want is an iso 8601 friendly stamp!

any ideas?  [here's a runnable example with docker](https://github.com/cdaringe/httpd-log-formatting-biff). thanks!

strftime ref: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217417/apache-log-format-timestamp-unable-to-get-timezone-offset

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I figure I'll put a correct answer here in case anyone stumbles across it like I did.

ErrorLogFormat and LogFormat are provided by different modules and have different format strings. ErrorLogFormat only supports very limited time formatting.

ErrorLogFormat: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlogformat

LogFormat: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

Answer (score 0):

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %{%FT%T%z}t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

emits

```
127.0.0.1 - - 2021-03-09T19:07:07+0000 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
```